# Use of accessor properties in JavaScript SDK design?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, api-design

I am designing a JavaScript SDK that is meant to make working with a specific, complex REST API simpler by abstracting away some of the complexity.

Some of the objects that the SDK will provide will need to expose properties that can be set and retrieved.

I have used and studied other JavaScript SDKs, and explicit getter/setter functions seem to be used almost universally in favor of accessor properties.

Some examples to illustrate what I mean:

**Explicit getter/setter functions**

```
function Widget() {
    return {
        setName: function(name) {
            //Sanitization, error checking, etc, could go here.
            this.name = name;
        },
        getName: function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

var widget = new Widget();
widget.setName("Testing");
w.getName(); //"Testing"
```

**Accessor property**

```
function Widget(name) {
    //Internal property that is modified by the accessor property.
    this._name = name;
}
Object.defineProperty(Widget.prototype, "name", {
    get: function() {
        return this._name;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        //Sanitization, error checking, etc, could go here.
        this._name = value;
    }
});

var widget = new Widget();
widget.name = "Testing";
widget.name; //"Testing"
```

To me, the most important distinction here isn't the actual implementation, but how objects are manipulated by the end user; via function calls in the first case, and via direct assignment in the second case.

Both implementations allow for error checking/sanitization when setting a value, and mutation of an internal value on-the-fly when retrieving it.

**So, why do most SDKs seem to avoid using accessor properties?** Is it a bad idea to use them? If not, when is it appropriate to use them instead of explicit getter/setter functions?  Here are some reasons I thought of:

- Lack of support in older web browsers
- Possible developer confusion when inspecting the objects in a development environment/web browser
- Possible developer confusion if they don't expect direct assignment to have side effects

If the language provides an explicit mechanism for this purpose (accessors), why is it more popular to "reinvent the wheel" with explicit getter/setter functions?

Comment: I think this is opinion based. But I prefer the first case because it is *simple*. Acessors makes your code bigger and confusing(as you said) to do the exactly same thing as the first case you proposed.

Comment: There's also the simpler possibility to not use accessors when not needed. Don't make your JS code look like Java.

Comment: @dystroy It's worth mentioning that there is also going to be a Java SDK which serves a similar purpose, so in this case there might be some benefit in the two having similar-looking APIs. I realize that this idea needs to be balanced with what is appropriate for both languages.

Comment: most SDKs probably want ot run on IE8. that's the only good reason i can see

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that some people still use IE8 and lower, which lack usable support for Object.defineProperty.  For people trying to design a generally accessible SDK that can be used in these kinds of environments, this is a non-trivial problem to work around.  Getters and setters don't have this problem.